# Multicolumn with different number of rows

Tags: multicol

I am writing an exam with 3 sections. At the end, for self-assessment a key is provided. This key is what I am struggling with, since after creating 3 columns, I need to figure out a way to have 19 rows in first column and 14 each in the others.

`\newpage`
`\section{Answer key}`
`\begin{multicols}{3}`
`\textbf{SECTION I}`
`\begin{enumerate}`
`\item A`
`\item E`
`\item D`
`\item C`
`\item D`
`\item A`
`\item A`
`\item A`
`\item A`
`\item A`
`\item A`
`\item A`
`\item A`
`\item A`
`\item A`
`\item A`
`\item A`
`\item A`
`\end{enumerate}`
`\textbf{SECTION II}`
`\begin{enumerate}`
`\item A`
`\item E`
`\item D`
`\item C`
`\item D`
`\item D`
`\item B`
`\item A`
`\item D`
`\item D`
`\item B`
`\item C`
`\item E`
`\end{enumerate}`
`\textbf{SECTION III}` 
`\begin{enumerate}`
`\item A`
`\item A`
`\item A`
`\item A`
`\item A`
`\item A`
`\item A`
`\item A`
`\item A`
`\item A`
`\item A`
`\item A`
`\item A`
`\end{enumerate}`
`\end{multicols}`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/82917) Please provide a full [minimal working example](https://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/82917) starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` instead of a code snippet. This makes our lives easier and increases the chance of people helping you.

Comment: I changed the tag from `multicolumn`, which refers to the `\multicolumn` command that can be used to merge cells in a table to the `multicol` tag wich refers to the `multicol` package that provedes the `multicols` environment you use in your code.

Comment: A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it). There is no need to enclose every line of code into an individual set of backticks `\`` as this is more used for inline code as opposed to code blocks.

Comment: Please be aware that the `multicol` package attempts to balance the column heights, which leads to equally tall columns. Since you seem to want to get columns with differing numbers of rows, a different approach could be easier. Probably a `minipage`-based approach is more suitable here:

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}

\newpage
\section{Answer key}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
\textbf{SECTION I}
\begin{enumerate}
\item A
\item E
\item D
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
\textbf{SECTION II}
\begin{enumerate}
\item A
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
\textbf{SECTION III} 
\begin{enumerate}
\item A
\item A
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}` for example should result in the expected output.

Comment: Thanks @leandriis I will try the `\hfill` and repot back.