# Align left first column title

Tags: multicol

I am writing an exam with 3 sections. At the end, for self-assessment a key is provided. In the key, I have 3 columns - 1 for each section. At the top is the section title. While column 2 and 3 titles align left nicely, the first column title doesn't :-(

```
\newpage 
\section{Answer key}  
\begin{multicols}{3} 
\textbf{SECTION I} \\ 
\textbf{Section Name}  
\begin{enumerate} 
\item A 
\item E 
\item D 
\item C 
\end{enumerate} 
\textbf{SECTION II} \\ 
\textbf{Section Name}   
\begin{enumerate} 
\item A 
\item E 
\item D 
\item C 
\end{enumerate} 
\textbf{SECTION III} \\ 
\textbf{Section Name}  
\begin{enumerate} 
\item A 
\item A 
\item A 
\item A 
\end{enumerate} 
\end{multicols}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two alternative approaches either based on `tabularx` or on side by side minipages.

As already mentioned [in a comment on your previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/600940/multicolumn-with-different-number-of-rows#comment1507100_600940), I'm quite certain, a `multicol`-based approach is not ideal for such a situation.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\newpage 
\section{Answer key}  

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}XXX@{}}
\textbf{SECTION I}  & \textbf{SECTION II} & \textbf{SECTION III}\\ 
\textbf{Section Name} & \textbf{Section Name}  & \textbf{Section Name} \\
\begin{enumerate} 
\item A 
\item E 
\item D 
\item C 
\end{enumerate} 
&
\begin{enumerate} 
\item A 
\item E 
\item D 
\item C 
\end{enumerate} 
&
\begin{enumerate} 
\item A 
\item A 
\item A 
\item A 
\end{enumerate} 
\\
\end{tabularx}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
\textbf{SECTION I} 
 
\textbf{Section Name}  
\begin{enumerate} 
\item A 
\item E 
\item D 
\item C 
\end{enumerate} 
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
\textbf{SECTION II} 

\textbf{Section Name}   
\begin{enumerate} 
\item A 
\item E 
\item D 
\item C 
\end{enumerate} 
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
\textbf{SECTION III}
 
\textbf{Section Name}  
\begin{enumerate} 
\item A 
\item A 
\item A 
\item A 
\end{enumerate} 
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```